# How to redirect to correct pages after permalink structure change

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess

I am changing my permalink structure from `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` to `/%category%/%postname%/`.
Is it possible to redirect old links using old permalink structure to the new link? Possibly via the postname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress should handle all redirections correctly, without you needing to worry about them. For example, if your old post was http://example.com/2012/10/11/i-like-stackexchange any links should auto-magically be redirected to http://example.com/favorite-things/i-like-stackexchange. I just tested it on a site with Wordpress 3.4 installed, and it worked just fine. Wordpress can *read your mind*.

Comment: while this does work in *most* cases, it may not be the most efficient way to handle it. WordPress isn't aware of your previous permalink structure and uses a `LIKE` query to find the closest match. You can see the mechanism responsible for this in `wp-includes/canonical.php` function `redirect_guess_404_permalink`.

Comment: Oh right, I wasnt aware WordPress has such a feature.

Comment: Milo, what's a good alternative then? Interested minds want to learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you change your permalinks WordPress doesn't always catch all the URLs that were changed. Luckily, there is a code solution from yoast: https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php

Enter the old structure, new structure, and it outputs redirect code.

Works every time I used it.